# Possible reason for unwanted page refresh in componentWillMount

Tags: reactjs, redux

After Login I want to show a license agreement page.
To show the license I used this code

index.js

```
componentWillMount(){

        this.props.actions.user.LicenseAgreement();
    }
```

action.js

```
export const LicenseAgreement = () => {
    return(dispatch) =>{
        authService.LicenseAgreement()
            .then((response) =>{
                window.location.href="/";
                dispatch({type: LICENSE_AGREE, payload:response});
            })
            .catch((error)=>{
                notification.error({
                    message: 'User',
                    description: error.message,
                })
            })
    }
}
```

reducer.js

```
case LICENSE_AGREE: {
            return{...state, agreement: action.payload.data.text}
        }
```

The problem is that the page refreshes before clicking **Agree** button .
But when I commented `componentWillMount()` there was no refreshing.

So how could I stop refreshing of this page?

Comment: `window.location.href="/";` should refresh the page. how does `authService.LicenseAgreement()` work(I mean should this reloading happen only after some response from user)? PS and it does not make sense to combine changing `window.location.href` and then calling the `dispatch` since page data will be reset on reloading

Comment: Also componentWillMount is deprecated because a bad place for such code;

Comment: Move the api call to `componentDidMount` as a change in store will trigger a re-render it will again call `componentWillMount` and keeps going. Also remove the `window.location.href` as @skyboyer said.

Comment: @skyboyer , the code worked when I removed `window.location.href="/";`

Answer (score 0):

Use `componentDidMount` life cycle and remove `window.location.href`. Also to avoid refreshing, you can user Router